# PHP singular and plural text editing

Tags: php

I have a sentence like this:

```
<h5>There are <?php echo $total_results_count; ?> results waiting for you!</h5>
```

How could I modify this to say:

```
There is 1 result waiting for you!
```

if there is only 1 result.

Comment: use If ... else ...statement...  $total_results_count > 1 ..... else

Comment: did any of the answers helped you?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I used Masoud answer but I think many of the others would work as well. I don't however understand why my question got -3 and a lot of people who gave good answers got -1?

Comment: @ron you can give every one with -1  a plus so we have 0 again :P

Comment: @Ron - You got -1 because your question is too basic, you could have googled it and found your answer easily. I got -1 because of a typing mistake, putting `if else` coeds in wrong order, then I fixed it though :)

Comment: @Ron - By the way, you should mark as **answer** the one that worked for you, for the sake of Stack Overflow rules

Comment: @SuperDJ, I tried to add +1 but the website does not allow me to do so. It says I need a reputation of 15 to do so.

Comment: @Masound, I marked your answer. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<h5><?php
if ($total_results_count > 1) {
  echo 'There are ' . $total_results_count . ' results';
}
else {
  echo 'There is ' . $total_results_count . ' result';
} ?> waiting for you!</h5>
```

Comment: @Ron - No worries :) Please accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Get results into a variable. Then,

```
if($count == 1){
  str_replace("are results","is 1 result ","There are results waiting for you!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As easy as:`<h5>There <?php if($total_results_count>1) echo "are"; else echo "is" $total_results_count. " result"; if($total_results_count>1) echo "s";?> waiting for you!</h5>`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if( $total_results_count > 1 ) {
    echo '<h5>There are '.$total_results_count.' results waiting for you!</h5>';
} else {
    echo '<h5>There is 1 result waiting for you!</h5>';
}
```